# Roulette Simulation Rigid Body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I am currently making an roulette simulation.
I have 4 main objects: the bowl, the sphere, the spinner in the middle and the separators which separate the numbers (I don't know the correct name for these).
I have animated the spinner to rotate on the z axis and linked the separators to it, so they rotate with it. The ball runs in the opposite direction.
I have set to origin for all objects to center of mass. All objects are declared as passive, except for the sphere.
The bowl is declared as mesh, the separators as convex hull (Base), and the spinner also as mesh. I have also increased the steps per second to 1.000 and the solver iterations to 100, but I always get the same strange behavior.
The problem now is that as the ball collisions with the separators, the ball bounces off extremely from the separators.
I have looked at several videos from youtube of an roulette wheel, and that's not the typical behavior of the ball.
I have set the bounciness on everything to 0 but it still behaves like that.
I am already going crazy about this problem, I really hope somebody has a solution for me :)

Comment: If it helps I can post the file :)

Comment: upload here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question to add the link